# Question on Tachyon Correlator (GSW)

Tags: string-theory

I'm reading through chapter 7 of Green-Schwarz-Witten and I have a problem with the derivation of the M-tachyon correlation function. Basically I'm trying to get 7.A.17 from 7.A.12 and eq 7.A.22 in the appendix of the first volume.

Basically I want to prove:

$$\langle\frac{V(k_1,y_1)...V(k_M,y_M)}{y_1...y_M}\rangle=\prod_{i < j}(y_i-y_j)^{k_ik_j}$$

with $V(k_i,y_i)=e^{ik_iX(k_i)}$

If I try to get this by just plugging everything into $\langle:e^{A_1}:...:e^{A_M}:\rangle=e^{\sum_{i<j}<A_iA_j>}$ using $\langle X(y_i)^{\mu}X(y_j)^\nu\rangle=-\eta^{\mu\nu}log(y_i-y_j)$ I somehow still have the $\frac{1}{y_1...y_M}$ factor in the formula above existing on the right hand side of the first equation. How is that cancelled in this approach? I dont see it.

More specifically I have

$\langle\frac{V_1...V_M}{y_1...y_M}\rangle=\frac{1}{y_1...y_M}\langle V(k_1,y_1)...V(k_M,y_M)\rangle=\frac{1}{y_1...y_M}e^{(\sum_{i<j}k_i^\mu\langle X_iX_j\rangle k_j^\nu)}=\frac{1}{y_1...y_M}e^{(\sum_{i<j}k_ik_jlog(y_i-y_j))}=\frac{1}{y_1...y_M}\prod_{i<j}(y_i-y_j)^{k_ik_j}$

which is the result I want to have up to that nasty prefactor that I cant make sense of.

Comment: +1 : While the logic of the appendix is clear : the tachyon vertex $V_0$ is separated into a zero-mode $Z_0$ vertex, and a non-zero mode $W_0$ vertex, with $V_0=Z_0 W_0$, and so,to get the correlation function : $\langle V_0(k_1,y_1) ...V_0(k_M,y_M) \rangle$, one have to multiply the correlation function of the zero-modes ($7.A.16$) and the correlation function of the non-zero modes ($7.A.13$), it is not clear for me how to obtain $7.A.17$ from  $7.A.12$ and  $7.A.22$...

Comment: @Trimok: I totally agree. I actually find it a bit weird, because they explicitely say that it is possible to get 7.A.17 from 7.A.12 and 7.A.22 on page 432 on the bottom. In fact this issue pops up in the later parts of chapter 7 for more complicated vertex operators as well..so I'm desperate to understand it :)

Comment: A possible hint should be to consider $y_1....y_m$ as a "measure", which does not change the general "behaviour" ($(y_i-y_j)^{k_i.k_j}$). For instance, , with $V'(k,y) = V(k, \frac{1}{y})$, we have  the same "behaviour", but with a different "measure". So, it maybe has to do with the different symmetries of string theory.

Comment: Wouldn't that change $(y_i-y_j)^{k_ik_j}$ to $(y_i-y_j)^{-k_ik_j}$? Btw, thanks for intervening at the physicsforums :D

Comment: In fact, this would give $(\frac{1}{y_i} - \frac{1}{y_j})^{k_i.k_j} = (\frac{y_j-y_i}{y_iy_j})^{k_i.k_j}$ (And in tree-level amplitudes, you have to take in account momentum conservation and mass shell conditions, so, I think that you will find that the measures are not so different ). In fact, in chapter $7.1$, one discusses open string, so tree amplitudes concerns vertex at the boundary (a circle) represented by quantities $0 \leq z_i \leq1$. In chapter $7.1.3$, one uses $7.1.1$ and $7.1.2$ in expression $7.1.15$ to get $7.1.26, 7.1.27$ .

Comment: In the last equations, you see that quantities $y_i$ are defined from the $z_i$, with  $0 \leq y_i \leq1$. So, the natural quantity is in fact $\frac{V(k,y)}{y}$. You may see this in $7.1.40, 7.1.42$. So, the choice of convention $0 \leq y_i \leq1$ is special, and, for instance, we could have done the choice $1 \leq y_i \leq +\infty$. In fact, when I look at the Polchinksi Vol $1$ p $180$, these different domains correspond to different cyclic orderings, and Moebius invariance is used to exchange the domains.

Comment: @Trimok: Thanks for your answers. My problem is that GSW say on page 432 that 7.A.22 is supposed to be the generalization of 7.A.11 including zero modes. Now those zero modes were (due to 7.A.16) responsible for cancelling the $\frac{1}{y_i...}$ factors so the must somehow come out of 7.A.22 here, mustn't they?

Comment: Sorry if I'm so persistent about this :) I do see the issue with ordering of the states but that gives just rise to phase factors as explained also in the appendix (e.g. 7.A.30), right? So, as I said, somehow the zeromode contributions that cancel the 1/y stuff must come out of the basic two-point X correlator...I just don't see it :)

Comment: $7.A.30$ does not discuss about the domain $1 \leq y_i \leq +\infty$ I think that the condition $0 \leq y_i \leq1$ is very special. Moreover, in $7.A.22$, you have a $\lambda$, which should have a $[L]^2$ dimensionality. In Polchinski conventions, you have a $\alpha'$ here, with $-\infty \leq y_i \leq +\infty$.

Comment: To be fair, a correct exercise would be to compare GSW and Polchinkski derivation of the four tachyon open string amplitude (the Veneziano amplitude), because the result is the same !!!, while the conventions are different...